# React Bootstrap Form.Control default value not taken

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, default-value

I am trying to make a modal that you open upon a click of a button for a specific student and try to add a grade for that student. But I face a problem - whenever I try to put a poor mark (which is the default one) from the dropdown, it doesn't get taken into consideration and is not added in the table with the student's marks (which is taken from student.firstSemester in this case). I don't understand why the default value does not get into consideration when I try to type it in right away (otherwise changing to any other grade and then to the Poor one works...)? Can you suggest an improvement for this? (btw I'm very much a beginner so the code quality is not high and I'm sorry for that).

````
const GradesTable= ({selectedClass, displayedSubj}) => {
    let students = selectedClass.students;
    const {t} = useTranslation();
    const [isInEditMode, updateIsInEditMode] = useState(false);
    const secondTermStartsAt = new Date('2021-02-01T22:00:00.000+0000');
    const [currentUser, updateUser] = useState(null);
    const [isOpenModal, openModal] = useState(false);
    const [studentNames, setStudentNames] = useState(undefined);
    const [studentGrade, setGrade] = useState(undefined);
    const [description, setDescription] = useState(undefined);

    let allGrades = [
        {key : "2", name : t('journal table.grades.poor')},
        {key : "3", name : t('journal table.grades.average')},
        {key : "4", name : t('journal table.grades.good')},
        {key : "5", name : t('journal table.grades.very good')},
        {key : "6", name : t('journal table.grades.excellent')},
    ];

    const setOpenModal = (value, names) => {
        openModal(value);
        setStudentNames(names);
    }

    useEffect(
        () => {
            if(!currentUser){
                const user = AuthService.getCurrentUser();

                if (user) {
                    updateUser(user);
                }
            }

            if(displayedSubj && students){
                setTableData(populateTableData(students));
            }},
        [displayedSubj, students, currentUser]
    );

    const flatmapArr = (arr) => {
        return [].concat.apply([],arr);
    }

    const saveGrade = (value) => {
        var grade = {
            id: null,
            date: new Date(),
            description: description,
            mark: studentGrade,
            subject: getCurrentSubject(),
            byWhom: currentUser.teacher
        };
        
        var currentStudent = tableData.filter(student => student.names === studentNames)[0];
        var student = students.filter(stud => stud.id === currentStudent.id);
        student[0].grades.push(grade);
        try {
            StudentService.updateStudent(student[0]);
        } catch(error) {
            alert(error.stack);
        }
        setOpenModal(false);
    }

    const handleGradeChange = (grade) => {
        setGrade(grade);
        assignGradeValueToStudent(grade);
    }
  
    const assignGradeValueToStudent = (grade) => {
        var currentStudent = tableData.filter(student => student.names === studentNames)[0];
        if(isEmpty(currentStudent.firstSemester)) {
            currentStudent.firstSemester = currentStudent.firstSemester + grade;
        } else if(currentStudent.firstSemester.substring(currentStudent.firstSemester.length-1, currentStudent.firstSemester.length) === studentGrade) {
            currentStudent.firstSemester = currentStudent.firstSemester.substring(0, (currentStudent.firstSemester.length-1));
            if(isEmpty(currentStudent.firstSemester)) {
                currentStudent.firstSemester = currentStudent.firstSemester + grade;
            } else {
                currentStudent.firstSemester = currentStudent.firstSemester + " " + grade;
            }
        } else {
            currentStudent.firstSemester = currentStudent.firstSemester + " " + grade;
        }
    }

    const setCloseModal = () => {
        debugger;
        var currentStudent = tableData.filter(student => student.names === studentNames)[0];
        if(!isEmpty(currentStudent.firstSemester)) {
            currentStudent.firstSemester = currentStudent.firstSemester.substring(0, (currentStudent.firstSemester.length-1));
        }
        setOpenModal(false, undefined);
    }

    return(
        <div>
            {isOpenModal && 
                <Modal.Dialog>
                    <Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Title>
                            {t('journal table.adding a grade')} <b><i>{studentNames}</i></b>
                        </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>

                    <Modal.Body>
                        <Form.Row>
                        <Form.Group as={Col} md="3" controlId="empty" />
                        <Form.Group as={Col} md="6" controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect1">
                                <Form.Label>{t('journal table.grade')}</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                name='grade' 
                                as="select" 
                                defaultValue={''}
                                onChange={(event) => handleGradeChange(event.target.value)}>
                                    {allGrades && allGrades.map(grade => 
                                        <option key={grade.key} value={grade.key}>
                                            {grade.name}
                                        </option>
                                    )}
                                </Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Form.Row>

                        <Form.Row>
                            <Form.Group as={Col} md="2" controlId="empty" />
                            <Form.Group as={Col} md="8" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
                                <Form.Label>{t('journal table.description')}</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                name='description'
                                type="text"
                                onChange={(event) => setDescription(event.target.value)}/>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Form.Row>

                    </Modal.Body>

                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => setCloseModal(false, undefined)}>
                            {t('journal table.close')}
                        </Button>
                        <Button variant="primary" onClick={(val) => saveGrade(val)}>
                            {t('journal table.save changes')}
                        </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal.Dialog>
            }
            {!isOpenModal &&
                <div>
                    <BootstrapTable
                        keyField="id"
                        data={tableData}
                        columns={columns}
                        hover
                    />
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default GradesTable;```
````

Answer (score 0):

Make your inputs controlled.

Initialise state with empty string:

```
const [studentGrade, setGrade] = useState('');
```

Replace "defaultValue" with "value" property and pass the current state:

```
<Form.Control
    ...
    value={studentGrade}
    ...
/>
```